# Script that post image

Tags: javascript, html, css, bootstrap-4

I'm making a project, it's a website that list some events, here its preview:

https://i.stack.imgur.com/W3a4U.jpg

I can modify the html and css and post more events like the image above, but it's not practical if I have to alter the html every single time I want to post an event or update it.

Is there any way to make a script to do it? Like a page where I just put things like event name, date, a image and stuff, and it generate an event like in the image above?

To be more specific, an script that makes this just by typing the information I want:

```
    <div class="item active">
      <img class="img-responsive" src="imagens/aero.jpg" alt="Image">
      <div class="carousel-caption">
        <h3>Aerosmith em São Paulo</h3>
        <p>Mais informações</p>



      </div>      
    </div>
```

Like a form that it automatcly creates it:

```
<div class="item active">
```

```
      </div>      
    </div>
```

Then i put an image:

```
   <div class="item active">
 <div class="item active">
   <img class="img-responsive" src="imagens/aero.jpg" alt="Image">
   <div class="carousel-caption">
          </div>      
        </div>
```

and then some info about it:

```
  <div class="item active">
      <img class="img-responsive" src="imagens/aero.jpg" alt="Image">
      <div class="carousel-caption">
        <h3>Aerosmith em São Paulo</h3>
        <p>Mais informações</p>
      </div>      
    </div>
```

and finally i post it and it gets like the image above.

Comment: we cannot see image

Comment: you need to make form or something to make entry of all information you want to display.

Comment: I'm  going to fix it, wait  a sec

Comment: Yes, but... How do I make a form to create a those div and classes inside a specific div of the code?

Answer (score 0):

You are talking about building a CMS. You may want to build your own, which can be fun, but likely you will want to use something that already exists and is easy to host. One easy to use example would be Wordpress.

Alternatively you could look at a static site generator (such as [hugo](https://gohugo.io/)), which will generate html pages for you on your computer, which you can then upload to your hosting provider.

If you go the Hugo route, you will have to create a page template for each event, and then make a data file (it can use several formats like `json` or `yml`) which contains the data for every event.

Comment: I'm in the dark here :( I must use this code in the project and make some form, script or both, that generates for me those divs

Comment: You can't generate new pages that other people will see without some sort of server to generate those new pages. There are many ways to set up such a server, but that is not simple. IF you want to just do it simply, you will need to use a CMS (content management system) that does that work for your, or something like hugo which generates the new pages on your own machine

Comment: @Lucky this is because the form has to post to some backend, which it seems you don't yet have, and that means you would need to set up passwords, and a database, and some dynamic language like node.js or php or something.